# Swing: does DefaultBoundedRangeModel coalesce multiple events?

Tags: java, swing, event-listener

I have a JProgressBar displaying a BoundedRangeModel which is extremely fine grained and I was concerned that updating it too often would slow down my computer. So I wrote a quick test program (see below) which has a 10Hz timer but each timer tick makes 10,000 calls to `microtick()` which in turn increments the BoundedRangeModel. Yet it seems to play nicely with a JProgressBar; my CPU is not working hard to run the program.

**How does JProgressBar or DefaultBoundedRangeModel do this?** They seem to be smart about how much work it does to update the JProgressBar, so that as a user I don't have to worry about updating the BoundedRangeModel's value.

```
package com.example.test.gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoundedRangeModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BoundedRangeModelTest1 extends JFrame {
    final private BoundedRangeModel brm = new DefaultBoundedRangeModel();
    final private Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { tick(); }
    });
    public BoundedRangeModelTest1(String title) {
        super(title);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.add(new JProgressBar(this.brm));
        getContentPane().add(p);

        this.brm.setMaximum(1000000);
        this.brm.setMinimum(0);
        this.brm.setValue(0);       
    }

    protected void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            microtick();
        }
    }   
    private void microtick() {
        this.brm.setValue(this.brm.getValue()+1);
    }

    public void start() 
    {
        this.timer.start();
    }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        BoundedRangeModelTest1  f = 
            new BoundedRangeModelTest1("BoundedRangeModelTest1");

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);     
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the nested class [`DoPostEvent`](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/Timer.java.htm) in the class [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and the comments on the field `notify`.

Addendum: Events from the [`DefaultBoundedRangeModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultBoundedRangeModel.html) are forwarded to the UI delegate by the [`fireStateChanged()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#fireStateChanged()) method of [`JProgressBar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html). The events are coalesced in the `EventQueue` when [`postEvent()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#postEvent%28java.awt.AWTEvent%29) is invoked by `repaint()`.

One way to follow the trail is to set a breakpoint in the UI delegate's `paint()` method and examine the call stack.

```
JProgressBar jpb = new JProgressBar(brm);
jpb.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI());
```

Comment: how does this relate to the events that the BoundedRangeModel produces? I don't have any listeners on the Timer other than the single ActionListener running at 10Hz.

Comment: @Jason S: I've elaborated above.